# Disallow Square Brackets in Question Titles [opened]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown, title

When a question is closed, its status is reflected in the title by appending `[closed]`. However, users tend to occasionally post a questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375919/php-question-about-variable-variables-sort-of) with square brackets in the title.

For one thing, isn't this what tags are for? Putting square brackets around a keyword in your title is just unnecessary. And more importantly, if square brackets were disallowed in titles, their presence would instantly alert people to a special condition within the system (like a question being `[closed]`).

One way this could possibly be implemented would be to display a suggestion to use tags if a user tried to enter '`[`' in the title of a question.

Thoughts?

Comment: Square brackets are used for tags, but not always. `Not able to $array[]` for instance is a valid use of square brackets.

Comment: It may be a valid use of square brackets but it's surely an awful question. "`Not able to $array[]`"?

Comment: look like you need my correct answer is no long correct!

Comment: @JohntheSeagull: That's a really poor question title.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**No.**

The following Objective C question would not be allowed.

> The "return [self square_root: i];" statement does not work with library.rich.b

**I *do* agree that the usage you are complaining about is undesirable**, but it can be cleaned up by SOpedians working for a S&W badge, and new users can be taught not to do use brackets inappropriately.

Comment: Good point. Also frustrating: array indexes and literals.

Comment: Agreed, good point; although as I've yet to hit 2K rep I'm still working towards getting edit privileges.

Comment: Patience, grasshopper.  The power will be yours soon enough.

Comment: doing it as a "title-begins-with-only" match is far safer

Comment: Better to automate this work. I'm certainly getting bored of doing it, though I still feel obligated to. It makes using SO tiring, for no particularly good reason. Why did we invent machines, again?

Answer (score 9):

Per Shog's prescient answer, this is what we went with. If the title **begins with a faux tag**:

`^\[[^]]+\]\s`

That is, it is of the form

> [jQuery] Entire page or multiple divs with '.mousemove'

We now block submission with

> title contains a [tag] prefix; please use the tag field to enter tags instead.

Comment: Would `*` not be better than `+`?  It would also catch titles with no space between the erroneous tag and the title.  E.g.: `[jQuery]Entire page or ...`

Comment: there are some code-y things about the form `[x]a` which make me nervous.

Comment: How about matching the contents of the erroneous tag with known tags? Or the top 100?

Answer (score 7):

I hate seeing what should be tags crammed into question titles. *Especially* as a prefix. So while I doubt this will really help much, I'd like to see it anyway, just to make editing them slightly easier.

The suggestion:

> Hey, it looks like you're trying to tag this question by putting things in square brackets - that's what the box below the question is for!

Would be *even better*!

Comment: I agree with your suggestion to go forward with the suggestion suggestion.

Comment: I would hate to see SO incivilly like an uncivil Office clip bad copy.

Comment: now implemented per my answer

Answer (score 4):

What about, instead of not allowing a perfectly valid couple of characters, that have done no harm to anyone, never get into fights, and never drink more than they can take (except for that one time in college), the way closed and migrated questions is changed so its more visible? Maybe the `[closed]` part of the title could be colored different, or make it bold, or make it `blink`.

Just make it different than normal title text, and stop pushing the poor `[]` brothers around.

Don't make me call the `<>` twins to beat you up for character racism!

Comment: Don't make it blink! Aaaaahhh!