# Dissuade askers from putting [tags] in question titles

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatic removal of tags from question titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70498/automatic-removal-of-tags-from-question-titles)

This has been [talked around](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70498/automatic-removal-of-tags-from-question-titles) [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20076/disallow-square-brackets-in-question-titles-opened), but with the idea of 
*automatically removing* or *disallowing* square-bracketed tags in titles. What I think would be better, and possible, would be an augmentation of the idea in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20076/disallow-square-brackets-in-question-titles-opened/20077#20077), namely:

- When the question has `[text in square brackets]`, **AND the text is an existing tag**, make a suggestion that tags should go in the tags field, not in the title

There's already code running in the title onblur - it does things like look for similar questions, or say 'That title is too short to be useful. Can you add some more detail?', so there's a place to do this check.

Comment: Since you acknowledge that this exact issue has been discussed here previously, why not leave an answer to one of those questions with your suggestion? As it stands, you've posted an entirely new duplicate question.

Comment: +1 It gets under my skin when someone puts pseudo-tags in brackets in the title!

Comment: @Cody the linked proposals are for *automatic* removal and *disallowing* this. I'm talking about a suggestion, you know, the whole 'Nudge' thing

Comment: Yeah, you mentioned that in the question. But the linked proposals are a very good place to post an answer with your suggestion. "No, I don't think automatic removal is a good idea because.... But how about if we just....?"  You even linked to someone's answer that did [exactly that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20076/disallow-square-brackets-in-question-titles-opened/20077#20077).

Comment: Can someone get rid of [closed] from the question title? :)

Answer (score 9):

I don't think adding this level of complexity is necessary. In my experience, this gets reliably edited out by the community within minutes.

Also, adding this as an automatic filter may lead to unexpected consequences (say, when trying to use mathematical notation).

Comment: The community has enough editing to do.  We aren't a garbage cleanup service for lazy askers.  You're right, though, that a strict filter is a bad idea.

Comment: I agree it gets edited out; but the only way a new asker learns that the community doesn't like this is by 'huh?' moments and observation. A little nudge would save everyone's time. I agree automated alteration would be asking for trouble.

Comment: @Aakash fair enough, a hint might work well.

Comment: "In my experience, this gets reliably edited out by the community within minutes." Doesn't mean we enjoy spending our time doing this.

Answer (score 6):

I think its a good idea.  Just pull the standard

> Sorry!  We can't accept this question!

on them.  Jerks, with their taggy titles.

Comment: What should I do if a user who has asked over 230 questions has pseudotags in over 80% of his titles? Okay, I eyeballed that 80% figure, but even if it's not true, there are a __lot__. (Yes, I am hoping that you will have a magic moderator solution so that I don't have to edit 200 posts and possibly infuriate this user.)

Comment: @PopularDemand: There is no magic.  There is only hard work.